# Display information from socket in a GUI with Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, user-interface, tkinter

Hope that somebody can help with this problem with socket and GUI.

I have a client that reads the info from a socket connection, then I want to display this info in a text box on the GUI, I use a threading to control it. In the GUI there are two buttons, to connect and read, and other to stop the connection, I use threading to do it. But I cannot manage how to pass the info ("recived") from the socket to a label or a text box in the GUI. I tried with global variable, with text box, labels, etc. But I cannot still reach it. Here is a sample of the code:

```
import socket
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, BOTH, Text, Menu, END
import threading
import tkFont

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.config(bg="gray")
top.geometry("600x600")
top.title("GUI")

s = socket.socket()
rueda = dict()

class Looping(object):
    def __init__(self):
        helv100 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size=100, weight='bold')
        self.B_start = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Start",font=helv100, command = self.button_start)
        self.B_start.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.B_stop = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Stop",font=helv100, command = self.button_stop)
        self.B_stop.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.isRunning = True
    def button_start(self):
        l.isRunning = True
        t = threading.Thread(target = l.measuredistance)
        t.start()        
    def measuredistance(self):        
        global recived
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(('172.17.18.21', 6000))  
        while self.isRunning == True:
            recived = s.recv(60)#number of bytes recived
            print recived
        else:
             print "Not connected to the wheel";    
    def button_stop(self):
        l.isRunning = False       
        s.close()
        print "Socket connection breaked"

l=Looping()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't update the content on the GUI, you just `print` it.

Try to pack a label to you main window like this:

```
...
myLabel = Label(top, text=recived)
myLabel.pack()
...
```

Then use config function to update content of this label.

```
...
myLabel.config(text=recived)
...
```

Comment: I packed the label within the GUI stuff. And with .config() try to update the values inside the "measuredistance" function. It works, thanks a lot!! Sometimes a simple stuff can solve "big" problems(big for me, I'm a beginner). Hope this answer can help somebody too.